# Allowing user to create a polygon in Modelbuilder ArcGIS10.1

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, modelbuilder

Is there a way to enable a user to create a polygon 'on-the-fly' through modelbuilder? The output would feed into a other operation such as 'Clip'.

Answer (score 5):

As suggested, the 'clip feature' in your model is going to be of 'feature set' data type.

First, create an empty feature class that will hold the schema of your feature set. This can be simply a polygon feature class with nothing else than a name:

[image]

Now in your model, right-click the Clip tool > Make Variable > From Parameter > Clip Features. Once the variable has been added, right-click the element and choose 'Make Parameter':

[image]

Now add your empty 'clip feature set' feature class to the map, and apply some symbology:

[image]

In your model, right-click the Clip Features element/variable, choose 'Data Type' and set to 'Feature Set', then choose to 'Import schema and symbology from:' the ClipExtent layer in your map document:

[image]

Once that's done, save and close your model.

To run the tool, and draw the polygon, double-click the model from ArcCatalog. You'll see the feature set variable with the symbology you created earlier in the tool:

[image]

Now you can start drawing your polygon on the map:

[image]

Notice it comes symbolized with the layer you created earlier then assigned to the feature set...!

Double-click to finish the feature set 'sketch', then click OK to run the tool. As long as your output has the 'add to display' option checked, you'll see the output on the map:

[image]

Comment: Great stuff. This works very well. Thanks for the very clear steps! Now, I'm just wondering if this would work if the polygon was clipping a raster layer?

Comment: What tool are you going to use for the raster clip?

Comment: MapBaker, Clip in Raster Processing, Raster, Data Management Tools. The raster that will be clipped is the output from a Cell Statistics. This is what I have in my current model but that just allows the user to select predefined county boundaries from a list. I would like to enhance this by enabling the input to be a user defined drawn polygon. Appreciate it.

Comment: I've found a solution to this by running a Clip (Analysis Tools/Extract/Clip) as per MapBakers answer above and then using the outputs of this to run the raster Clip (Raster Processing/Raster/Data Management Tools). There may be a more direct approach but this work around is fine for me and my model is now operational.

Comment: @Justin I think you're on the right track - the raster clip tool uses a raster as the input, so what you could also do is create a feature set variable on it's own, convert that to a raster, then use that as the input to the raster clip tool...

Answer (score 1):

While setting the properties for the input polygon, set the data type as a Feature set, and import a layer file created from a temp polygon layer for the schema and symbology input. Make it a parameter and this will allow users to draw in a polygon when the model runs.

[image]